# Enter single digit but the result have the tens digit when use python search value

Tags: python

When I input `7,17` but the result is

```
ifDescr.7
ifDescr.70
ifDescr.17
```

If I want the result is 7 and 17 when I input `7 17`, how do I code it?

```
ifDescr.7
ifDescr.17
```

text file

```
ifDescr.7
ifDescr.70
ifDescr.17
```

```
def search_multiple(file_name, list_of_strings):
    line_number = 0
    list_of_results = []
    with open(file_name, 'r') as read:
        for line in read:
            line_number += 1
            for x in list_of_strings:
                if x in line:
                    list_of_results.append((x,line_number,line.rstrip()))
    return list_of_results

def main ():
    folder = ('single.txt')
    verify1,verify2 = input ("Input number").split()
    matched_lines = search_multiple(folder,['ifDescr.' + verify1, 'ifDescr.' + verify2,])
    for x in matched_lines:
        print('Line = ', x[2])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. For debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including minimized code (for example, the second number, `17`, is irrelevant to the problem) and valid example input (since `7,17` and `70,17` seem to be invalid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is you are using `in` to check if string is in the line. As `ifDescr.70` contains `ifDecsr.7` in it,the result contains it as well. Try out the below function:

```
def search_multiple(file_name, list_of_strings):
    line_number = 0
    list_of_results = []
    with open(file_name, 'r') as read:
        for line in read:
            line_number += 1
            for x in list_of_strings:
                if x == line.strip():
                    list_of_results.append((x,line_number,line.rstrip()))
    return list_of_results
```